# Determine whether $x-1>0$ implies $x=0$ over a given domain

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I'm taking Mathematics for my degree,  mostly all the time I don't know how to answer mathematic question(not because I don't know the answer) and how to start to answer the question.

For Example :(logic) consider the statement $P(x) :x-1>0$ , $Q(x) :x=0$ . where $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ over domain A. $A=\{-1,0,1\}$ Determine whether $P(x)\implies Q(x)$ is true. So how do I start answering the question?

Comment: Can you explain what P and Q are? They seem like logical statements to me, but apparently they're functions? Try to carefully copy out what the question is asking. EDIT: Is it boolean algebra?

Comment: That edit changed the relation $R$ in $P R Q$ from implicatiom to greater or equal comparison. What was intended?

Comment: "all the time I don't know how to answer mathematic question(not because I don't know the answer)". That seems contradictory. Do you mean that you usually know the final answer, but not how to explain it? In your specific example, what does "not because I don't know the answer" refers to? Do you mean that you guess it is false but don't know  how to justify it?

Comment: If you already know whether $P(x)\implies Q(x)$ is true, and the difficulty is merely in how to _justify_ your answer, then you already know something about this problem that you have not explained in the question. Namely, is the implication true or false, and what makes you think so (in whatever way you can describe that, not necessarily in a mathematical way)?

Comment: By the way, if you're having difficulty signing in as user284608, try the help pages, or look at questions such as http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/12599/to-find-my-guest-user-account-again so that you can edit your question appropriately if the answers you have received are not answering your real question. (Also so that you can accept an answer if it _does_ answer your question.)

Answer (score 1):

One thing that may help is to decide whether you need a universal proof
or a counterexample. For instance, in order to prove that $x - 1 > 0$
implies $x > -1$ where the domain of $x$ is all integers, 
you would need to use facts of algebra and rules of logic from some
previously-developed sets of facts and rules in order to form a logical
sequence of statements.
(I cannot tell you what facts and rules would be appropriate to use in
your exercises, because it depends on context; for a given homework question,
it would be all the facts and rules presented in the class so far,
plus any others you may have been told you can assume.)

If $x$ is restricted to just the set $\{-1, 0, 1\}$ you might build a logical
sequence of statements to prove the fact just as you would for all integers;
but for this domain you have also have the ability to simply test the
statement for every possible value of $x$ and show that it is true
for each and every value.

On the other hand, if you are asked whether a statement is true,
and the statement is *false,* all you need to do is to come up
with *one* counterexample.
That is, if you can deduce (or even just guess) a value of $x$ that,
when plugged into the two parts of the implication, 
results in a false implication,
then all you need to do is to name that value of $x$ and evaluate
all parts of the implication assuming $x$ has that value.
Your answer might start like this: "Let $x = \ldots$."

So the first step in writing your answer is to decide whether the statement
is true or false. Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

You could try some algebra or brute force it by listing the table of all possible arguments and values and checking if those form a valid implication or comparison.

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
x & P(x) & Q(x) & P(x)\,  R \, Q(x) & \text{valid} \\
\hline
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
\hline
\end{array}
$$